# Firefox Bug or a CSS issue

Tags: css, firefox

I added a shadow and a background to a button, but the shadow causes the background to be interupted and broken as is described in the following screenshot.

[image]

What's strange is that when I remove the box-shadow of the button, the issue disappears.

This is my CSS :

```
.btnx3{
    background: #4687DF;
    border: 1px solid #2667BF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

I'm using Firefox 29.0.1, But what makes me ask this question is that I have other buttons and I don't have this issue.

I made sure to restart the browser, upgraded to 30.x.x, but the problem persists.

**Edit**
I tested the same code on JsFiddle, and it works normal : http://jsfiddle.net/nemzL/

Comment: Can you add a link to either a page or a jsfiddle ?

Comment: I don't know, but on jsfiddle, there's no problem http://jsfiddle.net/nemzL/

I don't know why I do have this in my localhost? also, the problem is only in that place, if I displace the button, there's no issue.

Comment: if theres no issue on jsfiddle its likely on yours. Css diff tools can be useful https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-diff/pefnhibkhcfooofgmgoipfpcojnhhljm?hl=en for chrome theres probably a similar one for firefox

Comment: Also, when I remove the border of the popup (the container of the form in which this button is put), the background changes back to normal

Answer (score 0):

This is not a CSS issue, it's apparently a Firefox bug. For some reasons :

1. There's no problem on chrome, and other browsers.
2. The problem is solved when you change css properties of other
   elements : Like the margin-top or the border of the container, or
   remove the shadows etc...
3. The same button, and the same CSS code works normally in different pages. (If I move the button to another place)

I will ignore this issue, since it's just related to the browser as you can see.

Thank you,

Comment: It cant be a firefox issue if the jsfiddle cant reproduce it.

Comment: But, look.. I have the same button, the same css code, when I remove the border of the container, the issue is solved. Can't be a CSS error either.